# How can we check that Google Tag manager works

Tags: android, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-sdk

I am developing an android application, and I used google tag manager to collect data.
When I run the project, the project work correctly and I have this in the console

```
V/GoogleTagManager﹕ Attempting to load a container from the resource ID 2131099648 (testconverteo.ismail.converteotag:raw/container_test)
V/GoogleTagManager﹕ The container was successfully loaded from the resource (using JSON file format)
V/GoogleTagManager﹕ Deleted 0 expired items
V/GoogleTagManager﹕ Attempting to load resource from disk
V/GoogleTagManager﹕ loadAfterDelay: containerId=GTM-NH9QCT delay=29045410
D/GoogleTagManager﹕ Setting previous container version: Nw$0
V/GoogleTagManager﹕ The Disk resource was successfully read.
W/GoogleTagManager﹕ GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException getting Advertising Id Info
V/GoogleTagManager﹕ Loaded client id from disk.
V/GoogleTagManager﹕ connecting to Analytics service
V/GoogleTagManager﹕ connecting to Analytics service
V/GoogleTagManager﹕ Sending hit to store  PATH: https:  PARAMS: sr=800x1216,  a=1964810494,  v=1,  ht=1434114913880,  an=ConverteoTag,  ul=en-us,  t=appview,  _u=.4nL,  tid=UA-62122818-2,  cid=538d87f1-f8ce-47bd-a0d0-c082a49be97e,  aid=testconverteo.ismail.converteotag,  av=1.0,
V/GoogleTagManager﹕ PowerSaveMode initiated.
V/GoogleTagManager﹕ PowerSaveMode terminated.
V/GoogleTagManager﹕ Dispatch running...
V/GoogleTagManager﹕ sent 1 of 1 hits
V/GoogleTagManager﹕ PowerSaveMode initiated.
```

It seems that data are sent, but I have nothing in the interface of google analytics.

Comment: You should be able to see data almost instantaneously in Real-Time reports if data is being sent. Make sure you are not blocking your own visits though. You won't see anything right away in the standard reports, as it usually takes about 24 hours for data to be processed.

Comment: @nyuen Thank you for your answer, in fact, I have not added any filter to the view, and even in the Real-Time I have nothing prouves that data have been sent.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? If yes, kindly share the solution.